# "composition" of two characteristic functions

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Suppose $\varphi_Y$ is a characteristic function. Let $p \in (0,1),\ q = 1-p$.

Show $\bar{\varphi}(t) = \frac{p}{1-q \varphi_Y(t)}$ is a characteristic function.

My thoughts:

Let X ~ Ge(p).

Then $\varphi_X(t) = \frac{p}{1-q \exp(it)}$

$\varphi_X(\frac{\ln(\varphi_Y(t))}{i}) = \frac{p}{1-q \varphi_Y(t)} = \bar{\varphi}(t)$

$\bar{\varphi}(t) = \varphi_X(\frac{\ln(\varphi_Y(t))}{i}) = E(\exp( i(\frac{\ln(\varphi_Y(t))}{i})X)) = E(\varphi_Y(t)X) = E(X) \varphi_Y(t) = \frac{q\varphi_Y(t)}{p}$

I don't think this can be right, but I also don't know what I did wrong. Can someone point out what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all logarithms of characteristic functions are not well defined. Logarithms in the complex plane are quite complicated. Even if we assume  that $\phi_Y(t)$ is positive for each $t$ your calculations are wrong.

$e^{(\ln (\phi_Y(t)) (X)}=((\phi_Y(t))^{X}$, not $(\phi_Y(t)) X$.